# How to add string on variable name using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hello guys i've got the following problem:
How can i set, that the input will be added to the variable?
The function Button_Hello_World will be used often and the string input is going to change ten times with different strings. The function is going to be reused thats why different strings will be implied later

```
var pointsString_To_Add=0;

onclick="javascript:Button_Hello_World(String_To_Add,5)"

function Button_Hello_World(string,variable)
{

       points+string = variable;
}
```

And now `pointsString_To_Add` should be `5`

Comment: `points+string = points;` is not valid syntax!

Comment: You don't say ;-)

Comment: Don't write event handlers as a string. It makes it easy to miss syntax issues, such as how you wrote `String_To_Add` without any quotes around it. Instead, assign a function to `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
pointsString_To_Add += points;
```

This is short hand for

```
pointsString_To_Add = pointsString_To_Add + points;
```

But I have no idea what your variable `string` was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign value to variable:

```js
var pointsString_To_Add = 0;
var String_To_Add = '';

Button_calculate_(String_To_Add, 5)

function Button_calculate_(string, points) {

  pointsString_To_Add = points + string;

  alert('pointsString_To_Add = '+pointsString_To_Add);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean somthing like this

```
function Button_Hello_World(string, points) {

    window[string] = points;

}
```

this will find value you passed and set the points to it

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are putting a variable in the function's args. Either you concatenate it and place it in the DOM or just put the string value there. Better to go with `addEventListener`:

```
var pointsString_To_Add=0;
var String_To_Add = ""; // put the actual value here.
var el = document.querySelector('theElement/tag/#id/.class');
el.addEventListener('click', function(ev){ // Add a click event here
    Button_Hello_World(str,points); // call the function
});

function Button_Hello_World(str,points){ // change to str as string is reserved
    points += str || 0; // if str is undefined then 0 will be added.
    console.log(points);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pointsString_To_Add=0, string_TO_Add = "";

onclick="javascript:Button_Hello_World(string_TO_Add ,5)"

function Button_Hello_World(string,points)
{

       pointsString_To_Add = string+points;
alert('Result Expecting'+pointsString_To_Add);

}
```